# In " A Quiet Place", Lee lights a fire ...does this imply other people nearby

Tags: plot-explanation, a-quiet-place

In " A Quiet Place", Lee lights a fire in the evening. At one point, the camera pans around him to show a ring of fire lit up.

Does this imply there are other survivors around his farm?

Answer (score 8):

My interpretation of this is that "yes" this implies other survivors in the valley that the farm is in.

We see Lee and Marcus come across a couple near their home, the woman who has recently been killed and the man who gives up and starts yelling.

The fire lighting may have become a tradition, a way of seeing that you are not the only people, but it also has practical value as a way of attracting attention should some sort of rescue ever come by.

Comment: It strikes me as one of the relatively few implausible parts of the story - fire is quite noisy when it is lit and fueled by paper, wood or coal.  They appear to have a supply of fire-lighting fluid in plastic bottles, but for everyone to have such a supply of fuel, and to use this every evening seems unlikely.

Comment: I don't think the film is meant to be tested against plausibility.  In a plausible scenario you wouldn't rig strings of lights and a way to make them turn red if/when there's a creature around; you'd rig up some loudspeakers and use them to corral the creatures wherever you want them to go.  Nor would you choose a rickety old farmhouse with huge, wide-open doors (and windows) everywhere as a good place to make a stand against predatory creatures.

Comment: Rigging up loudspeakers would work once, till the creature destroys them.  Shooting off fireworks, as they did, works as long as the fireworks last.